# Odd errors when testing on iphone, after device is disconnected

Tags: iphone, testing, ios4

I've noticed that when I upload my code to my test device, it works fine... right up to the point that I unplug it from the computer. I assume this is because it needs to connect to the debugger or something, but I'd very much like to ensure that the program will work once it's distributed. How should I go about setting up the program so I can test it without a direct computer connection?

-Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You app is probably launching in the debugger, and you are crashing that process.

First start your app (Build & Run), then quit the app on the device, and then quit the debugger (hit Stop in Xcode), **before** pulling the cable.  They you can (re)start your app on the device with no debugger in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Still got the weirdness with it not accepting my pre-generated SQLite file though. Need to sort that out, because I'll be wanting to ship an existing SQLite database with the program.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have your device plugged in to test your app. Just tap its icon from Springboard to launch it. I test my iPhone and iPad apps "offline" in this manner all the time.

Comment: This is becoming more and more puzzling then. Have any of your applications made use of the Documents folder, or SQLite databases? I've checked the file names and I know about case sensitivity in the iPod, so it's not that before anyone suggests it.

Comment: I think I'm narrowing down the problem. It seems that the program doesn't like it when I substitute the SQLite database on my computer into the device's documents folder. I don't know why this should be, as they're both made by the same program.